# Mongoose Schema Prototype

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have similar object for 4 different variables in a Mongoose Schemes and want to create a Object Array to be used in multiple times. I know I could use e.g. `Box: [Vector] array` but this is inconvenient. An example can explain it better:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Vector4 = new Schema({
    x: { type: Number },
    y: { type: Number },
    width: { type: Number },
    height: { type: Number }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entity', new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    version: { type: Number },
    AABB:     Vector4, // want the Vector Object here
    Box:      Vector4, // want the Vector Object here.
    Viewport: Vector4, // want the Vector Object here.
    Outline:  Vector4, // want the Vector Object here.
    ......
}));
```

I'm relatively new to Mongoose so I might be doing this Schema wrong. Any input would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoose schema is just a basic JS object. You would do something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Vector4 = {
    x: { type: Number },
    y: { type: Number },
    width: { type: Number },
    height: { type: Number }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entity', new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    version: { type: Number },
    AABB:     Vector4, // want the Vector Object here
    Box:      Vector4, // want the Vector Object here.
    Viewport: Vector4, // want the Vector Object here.
    Outline:  Vector4, // want the Vector Object here.
    ......
}));
```

The difference being that `Vector4` is not a `Schema`, but just an object.

Comment: Perfect! Could you link to the doc/api where it states this? I could not find it.

Comment: I don't think it's made explicit anywhere in the docs. But I deduced it from this page: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html